# PayPal billing plan not described error after login

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I´m testing billing plans in sandbox mode. This is what I do:

1. Create Billing Plan
2. Update (Activate) Billing Plan
3. Create Billing Agreement
4. Get redirect URL and redirect the user to
5. Log in with my sandbox account.
6. Login success – but message with "We could not process your request. Return to merchant-site"

All API calls are shown as successfull with 201 in sandbox API-Calls console.
[image]

Could someone help me where to debug this error?

Comment: Paypal. A multi-million dollar company who tell their users to ask questions on a free third party support platform ([StackOverflow](https://developer.paypal.com/support/)) and provide inconsistent and frankly poor coding architecture to their own developer codebases. [Sod this, use Stripe, you will reduce your (and your clients) stress levels](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-accept-payments-with-stripe--pre-80957)

Comment: You are right! But PayPal is an important requirement to my app, so I have to deal with it.